# Only one thread executes said function

Tags: c, multithreading

Im trying to build client-proxy-server application. It has to be multi- threaded. Following is client side of my code:

```
 int main(int argc, char* argv[])  
 {  
      //socket variables  

      printf("\nEnter proxy address:");  
      fgets(IP,sizeof("127.0.01\n")+1,stdin);  
      fputs(IP,stdout);  
      printf("\nEnter a port:");  
      fgets(port,sizeof("5000\n")+1,stdin);  
      fputs(port,stdout);  
      if((strcmp(IP,"127.0.0.1\n"))!=0 || (strcmp(port,"5000\n"))!=0)  
      {  
           printf("Invalida proxy settings. Try again...");  
      }  
      else  
      {  

          int threads=0;
          printf("Enter number of threads you want to generate :D");
          scanf("%d",&threads);
          pthread_t* thread_pool= (pthread_t *) 
            malloc(threads*sizeof(pthread_t));
          for(int i=0; i<threads; i++){
               pthread_t tid;
               thread_pool[i]= tid;
          }
          for(int i=0; i<threads;i++){
                 pthread_create(&thread_pool[i],NULL,execute,NULL);
                 pthread_join(thread_pool[i],NULL);


          }

          free(thread_pool);
          }  
          return 0;  
 } 


void *execute(){
      pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
      ex();
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
} 

void ex(){


   // create a socket  
           if((sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)  
           {  
                printf("socket not created\n");  
           }  
           memset(&client_sd, 0, sizeof(client_sd));  
           // set socket variables  
           client_sd.sin_family = AF_INET;  
           client_sd.sin_port = htons(5000);  
           // assign any IP address to the client's socket  
           client_sd.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;   
           // connect to proxy server at mentioned port number  
           connect(sd, (struct sockaddr *)&client_sd, sizeof(client_sd));  
           //send and receive data contunuously  

            printf("Type here:");  
            scanf("%s",&buffer);


            write(sd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));  
            printf("\nServer response:\n\n");  
            read(sd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));  
            fputs(buffer, stdout); 

            if(send(sd,buffer,strlen(buffer),0) < strlen(buffer))
               {
                    perror("Send Error!!\n");
               }

           char *source;

           if( recv(sd,response,RESPONSE_RECV_LIMIT,0) == 0 )
            {
                    perror("Recv : ");

             }
           source = strstr(response,SOURCE_START_IDENTIFIER);

           if(source == NULL)
          {
               source = strstr(response,SOURCE_START_IDENTIFIER2);      
           }    
           printf("%s\n",source);
           printf("\n %d",sizeof(response));


           printf("\n");       

           close(sd);  







}
```

In order to make it more understandable, I have posted the entire code. I can't figure out where the problem lies. No matter how many threads I create only one gets executed. 
Thanks in advance :)

Revision:
In the revised code, I have created a seperate loop for joining the threads. Problem lies where I’m asking for user input. Both threads get connected to server. Only one asks for input from user. And only one gets the response. Other one gets blocked along the way.

Comment: Edit your question and fix the indention.

Comment: `pthread_join` is blocking - hence no other thread is created while waitin for the current one to close...

Comment: It is always a good idea to post the complete code which people can try.

Comment: You are not using mutex judiciously. Locks are meant to protect critical section of code and having a lock around a complete function is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

`pthread_join` waits for a thread to exit, so what you are doing is:

1. Create thread 1
2. Wait for thread 1 to finish
3. Create thread 2
4. Wait for thread 2 to finish
5. Create thread 3
6. Wait for thread 3 to finish
7. ...

so obviously only one thread runs at a time.

What you should be doing is:

1. Create thread 1
2. Create thread 2
3. Create thread 3
4. ...
5. Wait for thread 1 to finish
6. Wait for thread 2 to finish
7. Wait for thread 3 to finish
8. ...

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some serious issues. First is with following piece.

```
void *execute(){
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
  ex();
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}
```

You are not using mutex judiciously. Locks are meant to protect critical section of code and having a lock around a complete function is not a good idea.

There are two main reasons why?

**1>** Threads have independent call stacks and hence instead of putting locks around the complete function, a good idea would be to identify what common resource or critical section of code will get accessed by all threads and protect that using locks.

**2>** If you are having lock around a function; then the lock will not be release until the function returns. And if you are unlocking the mutex after returning from function and then you create next thread then you are really not achieving parallelism because at one time there will be only one worker thread.

Another issue with your code is with the following piece which is redundant and does not do anything.

```
      for(int i=0; i<threads; i++){
           pthread_t tid;
           thread_pool[i]= tid;
      }
```

Lastly as mentioned in other comments which is pthread_join is blocking - hence no new thread will be created while waiting for the current one to close.

```
/******YOUR CODE******/
      for(int i=0; i<threads;i++){
             pthread_create(&thread_pool[i],NULL,execute,NULL);
             pthread_join(thread_pool[i],NULL);
      }
```

This should have been like

```
      for(int i=0; i<threads;i++){
             pthread_create(&thread_pool[i],NULL,execute,NULL);
      }
      for(int i=0; i<threads;i++){
             pthread_join(thread_pool[i],NULL);
      }
```

Comment: Upon your answer, I have  changed my code. Removed locks completely. The problem is that for 2 threads file gets returmed once. But when I kill the proxy server, only then is the second file returned